# Should move constructor be declared noexcept if a member of the class can throw when moved?

Tags: c++

MSVC 2019 gives a hint

> C26439: This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept'
> (f.6)

It refers to C++ Core Guidelines f.6: If your function may not throw, declare it noexcept. However, I am not sure whether all members of my class never throw exceptions when moved. In particular, there is OpenCV's `Mat`, which doesn't have `noexcept` specifiers in the declarations of its move and copy constructors. Moreover, the code can be used with different versions of OpenCV, where the move constructor may not even be available.

```cpp
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(MyClass&& other)
        : mat{ std::move(other.mat) }
    { }

private:
    MyClass(const MyClass&);

    cv::Mat mat;
};
```

Generally, if we know or assume that a member of our class may throw an exception, should we still follow this guideline and declare the move constructor `noexcept`?

I have seen other questions regarding `noexcept` in move constructors, but they discuss the implementation of the move constructor itself: we shouldn't be allocating memory, calling other code, or anything like that. Ok, I am not doing that. But what if there is just an instance of a class that may throw and we can't change that?

Comment: Related: [Are move constructors required to be noexcept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249781/are-move-constructors-required-to-be-noexcept)

Answer (score 0):

If something can throw you must think about the implications. Just marking the function noexcept might result in a call to `std::terminate`.
If you do not care you are free to catch all the exceptions within a noexcept function.

If a move contructor is not marked as `noexcept` it might disable the usage of move within certain `std` functions. See [Noexcept and copy, move constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627348/noexcept-and-copy-move-constructors)

Since your question is specific to the usage of `cv::Mat`. This type uses shallow copies by default. I do not like that design choice but one of the very limited benefits is that copying and moving are both rather cheap. The largest difference is the transfer of ownership.